# The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working

Tags: c#, transactions, ado.net, sqltransaction

**background**

I have some code which opens a sql connection, begins a transaction and performs some operations on the DB. This code creates an object from the DB (dequeue), gets some values and saves it back. The whole operation needs to take place in a transaction. All the code works perfectly without the transaction.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
    try
    {                       
        var myObject = foo.Dequeue(connection, transaction);

        var url = myObj.GetFilePathUri(connection, transaction);

        //some other code that sets object values

        myObj.SaveMessage(connection, transaction);
        transaction.Commit(); //error here
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {                    
        transaction.Rollback();
        //logging                
    }
    finally
    {
        //cleanup code
    }
}
```

**dequeue method code**

```
public foo Dequeue(SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(DEQUEUE_SPROC, connection) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, Transaction = transaction})
    {
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Read();
            ID = (Guid) reader["ID"];
            Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
            return this;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Get Path Code**

```
public string GetFilePathUri(SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(FILEPATH_SPROC, connection) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, Transaction = transaction})
    {
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Read();
            return reader["Path"].ToString();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

**Save Code**

```
public void SaveMessage(SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(SAVE_SPROC, connection) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, Transaction = transaction})
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = ID;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name;
        //other object params here
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

**The problem**

When transaction.Commit() is called, I get the following error:

> The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Quick edit to say I have read the other questions about this problem on SO, but couldn't find any related to ADO.net

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have had this issue before and the problem was the reader needed to be closed.
Try this:

```
public foo Dequeue(SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(DEQUEUE_SPROC, connection) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, Transaction = transaction})
    {
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Read();
            ID = (Guid) reader["ID"];
            Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
            reader.Close();//Closing the reader
            return this;
        }
        return null;
    }
}


public string GetFilePathUri(SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction    transaction)
{
    string filePathUri = "";
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(FILEPATH_SPROC, connection) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, Transaction = transaction})
    {
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Read();
            filePathUri = reader["Path"].ToString();
        }
        reader.Close();//Closing the reader
    }
    return filePathUri;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome :). The thing is we usually think that when we use "using" the reader will be close but using transactions it is not closed until you call Close() method.

Comment: Was pretty good. Good practice closing the reader sometimes it is a common mistake.

Comment: The reader is also `IDisposable`; the best practice would be wrapping its use in a `using` block. Then an exception will also close it properly.

Comment: Hi Zastai, I personally have used it in a using block and still getting the same exception when not closing it. So it may be a bug in .Net. Thanks

Comment: actually the reader is closed on dispose as I can find in [the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/Common/DbDataReader.cs,f7c2de36229de361) so it enough to wrap reader with `using`

Answer (score 12):

I had this problem when I forgot to use await on an async method that was doing the DB call - the connection was being disposed while the transaction was running because the program was not waiting for the query to complete before trying to dispose everything.

Answer (score 2):

We ran into this problem and while the accepted answer probably would've worked, it wouldn't have been the most correct thing to do -- it did, however, give us a clue as to what we were doing wrong.

In our case, there was more data to read. Here's a simplified version of the problem (using Dapper):

```cs
public Foo GetFooById(int fooId, IDbTransaction transaction = null) {
  var sql = @"
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Foo    WHERE FooID = @FooID;
    SELECT * FROM dbo.FooBar WHERE FooID = @FooID;
    SELECT * FROM dbo.FooBaz WHERE FooID = @FooID;
  ";

  using var data = await _connection.QueryMultipleAsync(sql, new { fooId }, transaction);
  var foo = data.ReadSingle<Foo>();
  foo.Bars = data.Read<Bar>();
  // Oops, didn't read FooBaz.
  return foo;
}
```

Even though `data` gets disposed, it leaves a "pending request" on the transaction, which then blows up later when `transaction.Commit()` is called.

The solution is to either read `FooBaz` records out of `data` or get rid of the unread `SELECT`.

Comment: solved my problem. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For who will come here in the future, I had this issue with a combination of `IQueryable` and `AutoMapper`.

I passed an `IQueryable` for mapping to `Mapper.Map<>(myData)` by thinking that since it maps data from a class to another, it also materializes it.

Apparently, I was wrong and the issue mentioned in the question was thrown when trying to `transaction.Commit()`.

#### Solution

As easy as forcing the materialization with a `.ToList()` in `Mapper.Map<>(myData.ToList())`.

Just wasted an hour finding that, I hope this will save some time for someone else.

Comment: `ProjectTo` works with `IQueryable`, not `Map`.